# Can't render elements in another form from inside a jQuery-tabs dynamically loaded tab

Tags: ajax, jsf, jquery-tabs, jsf-2.2

i have main page as that contains interests composite component and links for lazy loaded tabs as follows:

**1- profile page:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="../templates/application.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:myapp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/component"
    xmlns:p="http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough">
        <ui:define name="head">
    <title>Profile</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/assets/css/jquery/jquery-ui.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/assets/css/override-jquery.css" media="screen"/>
    <style>
        li
        {
            outline: none !important;
        }​
    </style>
    </ui:define>

<ui:define name="right-side">
    <div class="three-column right">          
    <myapp:interest bean="#{interestBean}" value="#{interestBean.interest}" id="interestCmp"></myapp:interest>              
    </div>
</ui:define>    
<ui:define name="content">
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="tab1" href="tabs/tab1.xhtml">tab1</a></li>
            <li><a id="tab2" href="tabs/tab2.xhtml">tab2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">head.ready(function(){$('.tabs').tabs();});</script>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**2- interests composite component:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="id" />
    <composite:attribute name="index" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    <composite:attribute name="bean" /> 
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation xmlns:myapp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/component">
<div >
<aside class="interests">
    <header class="header-w-flag icon-star">
        <h1>Interests</h1>
    </header>
    <h:form id="interestForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="showInterests" layout="block">
    <ui:repeat var="interest" value="#{interestBean.getUserInterests()}" >
        <div class="interest">
        <div class="interest-name"><a href="">#{interest.interestName}</a> 
        <h:commandLink  action="#{interestBean.deleteInterest(interest)}" rendered="#{permissionBean.isCurrentUser(profileBean.user)}" >
        <i class="icon-delete control-icon" style="cursor:pointer;display:none;"></i>
        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@this"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandLink></div>
        <div class="people-grid"> 
        <ui:repeat var="user" value="#{interestBean.getUsersByInterest(interest.id)}" varStatus="status" >
        <h:panelGroup id="interestedUsers">
                            <a title="#{user.firstName} #{user.lastName}" href="../profile/index.xhtml?id=#{user.id}"><img src="#{applicationBean.avatarBaseURL}#{user.avatarUrl}" alt="#{user.firstName}" /></a>
        </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:repeat>
        </div>


       </div>
    </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
   </h:form>
</aside>

        </div>
</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

**3- the tab1 code:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:myapp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/component"
    xmlns:p="http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough">

   <div id="tab1">
            <!-- feed here -->
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="posts" id="feedContainer">
            <h:form id="profileFeeds">
            <ui:repeat var="post" value="#{feedBean.feeds}" varStatus="status" >
                <myapp:feedpost value="#{post}" index="{status.index}"></myapp:feedpost>    
            </ui:repeat>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{feedBean.feeds.size()==0}">
                <div class="post blue">
                    <div class="post-content">

                        <h1>Nothing</h1>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>  

            <div class="post load"><h:commandLink action="#{feedBean.getMoreHomeFeeds()}" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-small">Show more feeds
            <f:ajax render=":feedContainer" ></f:ajax>
            </h:commandLink></div>
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </div>



</html>
```

**4- feedpost composite component that is linked from tab1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="id" />
    <composite:attribute name="index" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" />

</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation xmlns:myapp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/component">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="post">
    <div class="post-content">      




                <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                        <h1><h:outputFormat value="#{cc.attrs.value.title}" /></h1>
                </h:panelGroup>

tText value="#{baseBean.replaceWithHTMLBreak(cc.attrs.value.note)}" escape="false"/></p>
                </h:panelGroup>


        </div>
    <myapp:comments value="#{cc.attrs.value}"></myapp:comments>
    </h:panelGroup> 
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

**5- comments composite component that is linked from feedpost component:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="id" />
    <composite:attribute name="index" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" />    
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="comments" id="feedcomments">
        <div class="actions">

            <h:commandLink id="addToInterestLink" value="#{msg['action.addto.interests']}" styleClass="action-like"
                action="#{feedBean.addToInterests(cc.attrs.value)}">
                <f:ajax  execute="@this" render=":interestCmp:interestForm:showInterests"></f:ajax>
            </h:commandLink>

        </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

when clicking on tab1 link (lazy loaded jquery tab) that contains the comments composite component that has the link to render interests div in interest component, i am getting following exception:

```
<f:ajax> contains an unknown id ':interestCmp:interestForm:showInterests' - cannot locate it in the context of the component addToInterestLink
```

**NOTE:** one workaround i have found for the issue is to add the tab1 content statically to the page instead of linking it.

please advise how to fix that.

Comment: You seem to have edited the code in your question into an invalid shape. Using `:` in JSF component ID would only throw an IAE. In future questions, please copypaste real code unmodified. Otherwise you're only introducing red herrings and confusion.

Comment: @BalusC, i posted the correct code now, sorry i was not understanding the page code correctly, also sorry for confusing i promise i will not do that again.

Comment: There are 2 things weird with this code: 1) the `<f:ajax render>` doesn't use `:` prefix yet the error message mentions this; are you still showing real code? 2) Are you implying that it works fine when you replace `<ui:repeat>` by something more simple, like "hello"? And, there's one unclarity: is the `<myapp:interest>` a composite component with `<cc:interface><cc:implementation>`, etc? You namely keep calling it "composition", not "composite".

Comment: @BalusC, i corrected the render, error code now.
the link that has render function is inside tab in the page, when i try to click on the tab, i am getting the exception on console, so no render doesn't work at all because tab is not loaded.the myapp:interest is composite component, sorry for the confusion, i am still learning.

Comment: Well, my original answer still stands .. Use `render=":interestForm:showInterests"`. Didn't that work?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh, like BalusC pointed out, all chained ids should begin with `:`

Comment: @BalusC, i added another update that contains the cause of this exception.

Comment: In the future questions post a real SSCCE. When you post code, you should **always** ensure that anyone (including yourself!) will be able to reproduce the described problem by merely copypasting the provided code snippet unmodified straight into the `<h:body>` of a templateless page in an environment with all settings set to default (unless otherwise mentioned, e.g. web.xml params, etc).

Comment: @BalusC, i will do that, apologizes for confusing.

Comment: @BalusC, so any advises about the issue ?

Comment: Post a real SSCCE first.

Comment: @BalusC, full code is added now.

Comment: Thank you, but this is absolutely not an SSCCE, so it'll still require a lot of time to figure out the problem.

Comment: Just in case, SSCCE means "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example" (http://sscce.org/).... As BalusC said, something anyone can easily use to reproduce the problem, and then start working on a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in a nutshell and somewhat simplified (composite components actually don't play a role in the problem), your problem is here:

`profile.xhtml`:

```html
<my:composite id="interestCmp"> <!-- Yes, invalid code; just to summarize. -->
    <h:form id="interestForm">
        <h:panelGroup id="showInterests">
            ...
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</my:composite>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="tab1" href="tabs/tab1.xhtml">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab2" href="tabs/tab2.xhtml">tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>head.ready(function(){$('.tabs').tabs();});</script>
```

And somewhere in `tab1.xhtml`

```html
<h:form id="profileFeeds">
    <h:commandLink value="Add">
        <f:ajax render=":interestCmp:interestForm:showInterests" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

You're thus using [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) to have a tabbed panel with dynamic content. However, the tab page `tab1.xhtml` doesn't share the same JSF view as the main page `profile.xhtml`. It are physically completely distinct views. That totally explains why the `<f:ajax>` couldn't find the desired component in the component tree (the current view). It can only see components which are contained in `tab1.xhtml` itself. It doesn't see those of `profile.xhtml`. It can't even see those in `tab2.xhtml`.

It will only work if you preload tabs by `<ui:include>` instead of dynamically load them. This way the `tab1.xhtml` will physically end up in the same view as the desired component. Let's assume that you only need to do that for `tab1.xhtml` and the `tab2.xhtml` can be kept dynamically loaded. This should then solve your problem:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="tab1" href="#tab1_page">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab2" href="tabs/tab2.xhtml">tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1_page">
        <ui:include src="tabs/tab1.xhtml" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You only need to replace the `<?xml...?><!DOCTYPE ...><html xmlns...>` and `</html>` of `tab1.xhtml` (and actually also `tab2.xhtml`) by `<ui:composition xmlns...>` and `</ui:composition>` respectively. Because otherwise you end up in syntactically invalid HTML.

If you *really* need to have dynamically/lazily loaded tabs, then you'd better look for a fullworthy JSF component capable of the job, such as [PrimeFaces `<p:tabView>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewDynamic.jsf). Even more, PrimeFaces uses jQuery/UI under the covers for the look'n'feel, so many things will be very simliar to the current approach.